# The One-Electron Universe postulate is true - what simple change can I make to change the whole universe?

Tags: hard-science, universe

> The one-electron universe postulate, proposed by John Wheeler in a
>   telephone call to Richard Feynman in the spring of 1940, hypothesises
>   that all electrons and positrons are actually manifestations of a
>   single entity moving backwards and forwards in time. According to
>   Feynman:
>
> “ I received a telephone call one day at the graduate college at
>   Princeton from Professor Wheeler, in which he said, "Feynman, I know
>   why all electrons have the same charge and the same mass" "Why?"
>   "Because, they are all the same electron!"
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe

The supposition is that there is only one electron. It stands to reason that if I could change that electron, I could change the properties of the whole Universe.

Assume that the postulate is true.

**Question**

Given foreseeable science, what properties of a single electron could be changed? In theory, could we change the charge? Could we change the mass?

Comment: We need an Universebuilding.SE - Oh, wait, it's called [physics.se]. You will get the inevitable - "no, it's not possible because we exist" answers.

Comment: @Agrajag "Hardly ever sarcastic", eh?

Comment: If the postulate is true, then you can’t change an electron. Because many of the electrons around you at present are the future forms of the electron you’re planning to change, thus proving that you didn’t change it.

Comment: I am almost certain that this *hard science* question uses the word "theory" with a meaning different from the meaning it has in hard sciences...

Comment: @Mike Scott - Or are they past versions?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Some are past, some are future. You’d expect a roughly 50/50 ratio on average.

Comment: chaslyfromUK, Mike Scott has a great point, there are symmetry issues. For a decent answer to this you need to message @Sheldon Cooper. Tell him that he's the best and the greatest genius bar-none, he'll be a stand-up guy and help.

Comment: There's a complication in the form of muons and tau electrons. I suppose there might be only one of each ...

Comment: Beware that changing the universe has a 99.999999...(fade out, fade in)...99999% chance of destroying all life, present, future _and_ past, everywhere.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you read Asimov's _The Gods Themselves_ and Greg Bear's _Moving Mars_.

Comment: Just FYI the standard particle theory completely explains why electrons are identical

Answer (score 36):

### Disclaimer

Because my answer below throws a bit of shade at the other existing answers, and because I'm going for a bit of a flip, humorous, and somewhat defiant tone, I feel that I should point out that I'm a [real life physicist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/31790/danielsank) and most certainly not a crackpot :-P

### Rant

All the naysaying in the other existing answers, e.g.

- *"This universe is fundamentally impossible..."*
- *"[There] won't be anything you can change, because there won't be just one electron. The model is completely incompatible with current understanding of physics."*
- *"Whether the Wheeler postulate is true or not, under the known laws of physics, you can't change any of the properties of an electron. Mass, charge, spin, magnetic moment, etc. are all intrinsic properties. "*

seems out of place to me.
Even in a sober discussion with my colleagues in which we were to speculate on the future of physics, I wouldn't go around making statements about what certainly is and isn't possible.
The physics community has been so wrong so many times about how things will turn out even ten years in the future that such definitive statements of impossibility just seem imprudent.
Adding on top of that the facts that

- We're talking about quantum field theory here, which is already known to have some foundational issues and hasn't yet been reconciled with gravity, and
- *This is a world building site*,

I think a little bit of tempered imagination is in order.

### Alright let's actually answer the question

> In theory, could we change the charge? Could we change the mass?

Sure, why the hell not?
Electrons are presently thought of as excitations of the electron field, much like photons are units of excitation of the electromagnetic field.
The electron's "charge" is a word for describing how strongly the electron field interacts with the electromagnetic field.
Can we change that coupling strength?
Yeah maybe, who knows?

Imagine the first time someone discovers that sound is compression waves travelling through some kind of magical continuous medium; they might think that the speed of sound is intrinsic because that medium is unchangeable.
However, they eventually figure out that at smaller length scales, the sound-carrying-ether is not uniform and continuous, but rather a granular collection of billions of little particles of "air", all bumping into each other.
It's only when we zoom out and look at waves whose wavelength is much longer than (the space between) individual air molecules that the wave phenomenon of sound seems to exist in a continuous and uniform medium.
Once they know about the underlying structure of air molecules, they figure out that *changing* things about those molecules *changes* the speed of sound.
For example, they can heat or cool the molecules, or supplement them with some other type of molecules like $\text{He}$ or $\text{SF}_6$.

If the electron field has underlying structure, then it seems quite likely that we can mess with that structure to alter the properties of that field's excitations, i.e. change the properties of electrons.

...and we haven't even talked about the single-electron theory yet...

Suppose spacetime is a big old four dimensional bar with a cube-shaped cross-section.
That is, the spatial dimensions have finite extent but the time dimension goes to plus and minus infinity.
In that spacetime, the single electron's world line can be any path through this four dimensional bar.
Now suppose a being that lives in a twenty dimensional spacetime which contains our little four dimensional one comes along and pokes a hole in the electron field in our spacetime.
Now the electron's path can't be deformed in a way that would carry it through the hole.
Proper hole-punching could wind up tying our electron in knots around the holes!
Would that change it's charge or mass?
I dunno, probably not, but it would change *something* about the electron's physics because now the set of possible electron worldlines is topologically nontrivial.

A field's (particle's) mass is related to how much energy it costs to create an excitation in that field (a.k.a. create a particle).
Suppose the universe were a Mobius strip and suppose the energy cost of creating an electron is related to the length of the strip because the electron's world line has to make a complete unbroken trip around the strip.
Well then if a twenty dimensional alien could come in and cut a section out of our Mobius strip universe, then the mass of the electron would go down.

More?

Comment: "Well then if a twenty dimensional alien could come in and cut a section out of our Mobius strip universe, then the mass of the electron would go down." ; Wow that's very close to a real hypothesis; I've heard it said the coupling constant between mass and gravitational attraction depends on the mass of the universe.

Answer (score 11):

This universe is fundamentally impossible, since some electrons have their worldlines terminated in a black hole. Without a full working model of quantum gravity, we can't make any firm predictions about what happens to such electrons, other than the singularity is likely to end their existence. The black hole will inherit the charge, mass and angular momentum, but lose all the electron-ness of the particle's information (no hair theorem).

You can also have electrons terminated in beta capture events (which turns a proton into a neutron and the electron stops existing).

So, there won't be anything you can change, because there won't be just one electron. The model is completely incompatible with current understanding of physics.

Comment: Not to mention that beta decay produces electrons (or positrons) *de novo*, guaranteed to have had no prior existence.

Comment: I like the phrase, "This universe is basically impossible", I must say I frequently think that. If I wasn't living in it I wouldn't believe it.

Comment: The universe isn't fundamentally impossible: We don't know that it's possible because we don't know what happens to the electron inside the black hole. That's different to saying that we have proved that it's impossible.

Comment: I could be mistaken here. But I'm downvoting this because the question very clearly says **"Assume that the postulate is true"**. You are saying the concept is _impossible_, but many other threads here deal with _outright impossible_ things like magic and other fantasy devices. I don't know why it's difficult to imagine a universe where *most* of what we know comes out as true, but things are altered or handwaved where they need be.

Comment: I was hoping you'd use the term _future null infinity_...

Comment: @immibis But tylisirn mentioned the no hair theorem.

Comment: @forest Which is not proven to be true about the universe. (It might or might not be proven in general relativity, but we know general relativity is somehow wrong, because it's allegedly incompatible with quantum mechanics)

Comment: @immibis But saying "we don't know what happens" is misleading. We have some pretty good theories. You could just as well say that we don't know that we aren't living in a matrix (implying that we are). A better thing to say would be "it's possible that this universe isn't fundamentally impossible, if our current understanding of the universe is incorrect in a specific way".

Comment: @forest We also have a theory called CPT symmetry that says the universe is more-or-less time-reversible. That means it's equally possible for a black hole to spit out a bunch of matter as it is for a black hole to suck in a bunch of matter. So how come they don't? Well, one of the theories is wrong. Or maybe they do, eventually.

Comment: @FinnO'leary I understand, but there is nothing you can do to make a hard-science universe that fits the postulate that is interesting. It can have no gravity, no relativity and no nuclear reactions. And thus no planets, no stars, no life.

Comment: The postulate says there is one electron, it does **not** claim that it always will look like an electron to us and it **specifically says** that what we think is the electron is just a manifestation of a single something else. There is absolutely nothing in event horizons or nuclear phenomenon that contradicts that. It is the manifestation that changes or vanishes, the actual electron does not. Or would not if we assume the postulate and all that

Comment: @tylisirn Hard science fiction also allows handwaving. I wondered what is considered as hsrd science fiction. Well, both Jurassic Park, and Clarke's first Rama novel are commonly considered as such. I seem to recall both novels requiring a large amount of handwaving of the actual science involved. Particularly the second half of Rama. Sagan's Contact, which is also hard science fiction, deals with a machine that was fundamentally scientifically impossible when he wrote the thing

Comment: I always saw hard science fiction more as a way of story telling than the amount of science background of the things depicted. Many Asimov's hard science stories do not mention much of the science involved.

Comment: But even black holes conserve charge and eventually evaporate due to Hawking Radiation. So, if an electron falls into a black hole, something with -1 charge will eventually come out of it.

Comment: @Ville Niemi The whole point of Wheeler's idea was that the electron never changes. He as trying to answer the question of why all electrons appear identical with the same charge and mass. If that's not true, if the electron changes, then there's no point in adding anything as baroque as particles which propagate backwards in time into your theories.

Comment: @MarkOlson are you trying to say that Wheeler wouldn't have made the one-electron suggestion if electrons change or were not all the same? If so, he might not have, but I don't see how that is important to the question. "Assume it is true."  If it is true that there is one electron, _and the electron can change_, then Wheeler might not have made the suggestion, but Wheeler making the suggestion no longer matters.

Comment: @MarkOlson Yes, the electron does not change. All I am saying that when the situation surrounding the electron changes our observation of the electron will also change **regardless** of whether the electron changes. Mind you, your actual point is obviously valid, I was simply responding to the "obviously impossible" claim which is something else.

Answer (score 10):

Whether the Wheeler postulate is true or not, under the known laws of physics, you can't change any of the properties of an electron. Mass, charge, spin, magnetic moment, etc. are all intrinsic properties. They are not mutable by any known (or even to the best of my knowledge hypothesized) mechanism.

As to the postulate itself, as pointed out in comments and in tylisrn's answer, there are strong reasons to not believe that the Wheeler postulate is true. In addition to problems with any mechanism that results in the creation or destruction of a lone electron or positron, the Wheeler postulate runs into difficulties in explaining the observed imbalance of matter and anti-matter. If a single electron is zipping backwards and forwards through time, we should see it moving backwards as often we see it moving forwards. This would imply equal numbers of electrons and positrons, which we simply do not observe.